# Working with jQuery and PHP/MySQL tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a table created with PHP/MySQL results, http://www.fsma.co.uk/help/table.jpg.

When the user clicks the resend confirmation button, I have a jQuery script that runs a PHP script to send the email to that customer.

What I need is for that button to then change to text and give the returned mesage from the PHPscript, or for a new row to be added underneath to show the returned message.

I had it working, but no matter which button you clicked it used the same row. However, due to playing around with so many ideas, I no longer have that code.

Comment: Seems to be back now, but it wasn't there 45 secs ago.

Comment: Use the `jQuery.post` function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
The functions callback is the echoed content from your php function.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
$(".buttonClass").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post(url, data, function(response) {
        // hide the clicked button
        $(this).hide(); 

        // insert content from the called php function after the button
        $(this).after(response);
    });
});
```

Your php function has to echo the content you want to display instead of the button.

Comment: Thanks, but it just sends the form and goes to hte next page as normal.. 
sorry im sure its something simple, i just have no clue ! 8-(

Comment: I've updated my answer. [eventPrevault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) will prevent the default action to happen.

Comment: add "return false;" before the last closing });

Comment: thanks again but it still does the same... i have pasted the code for my form, and the Jquery here (http://pastebin.com/aPw1zgv2)

Comment: Does the jQuery.click() get triggered? What if you put an alert('test'); directly above the event.preventDefault()

Comment: Wrap your JS code into the [.ready()-function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
You also have do declare these variables: url, data...
I would suggest to learn the basics first.